# Dividing an interval into equal length segments, formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm working on a problem in which the author divides an interval into $2N + 1$ equal length segments per the graphic below.  How does one arrive at the formula for this sequence?   Is there a general formula that can be used to derive this?

For instance, I could write this using the sequence $[1, 1 + (1/N)), ... [1 + ((N-1)/N),2)$

[image: segments]

Comment: What do you mean with 'How does one arrive at the formula for this sequence? '?

Comment: Why choose $2N + 1$ vs the sequence I presented before the graphic?

Comment: Well, it depends on what is the purpose of the sequence, do you want to define integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Given an interval $[a,b]$, with $a<b$, and a positive integer $n$, there is only one way to divide it into $n$ equal parts. Each part would have to have length $\frac{b-a}{n}=\delta$ hence the sub-intervals must be
$$[a,a+\delta],[a+\delta,a+2\delta],\dots, [a+(n-1)\delta, b]$$